# Rational points in a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: number-theory

This is probably a very elementary question. If $U$ is a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, what can we say about the set $U\cap \mathbb{Q}^2$? Why can we find an ordered pair of rational numbers $(q_1,q_2) \in U$ where a rational number between $q_1$ and $q_2$ has a prescribed arbitrarily large natural number $N$ as denominator? (I mean representing $q_1, q_2$ in lowest terms.)

Thus, if I'm not wrong, we can always find an ordered pair of rational numbers (in lowest terms) in $U$ where a component has even denominator. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does the "prescribed denominator" need to be the denominator of both co-ordinates of the point $q$, or of at least one?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy, I've just edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: what happens when you remove from $\mathbb R^2$ the lines $\{q\}\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\times\{q\}$ for $q=\frac{u}{v}$ where $u\in\mathbb Z$ and $v$ is your prescribed denominator? Is the resulting set open and dense?

Comment: Alternative hint: if $B$ is any open ball in $U$ (or indeed any bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$), see if you can convince yourself that the set $B \cap ((\frac{1}{N} \mathbb{Z})^2)$ is finite for every positive integer $N$

Comment: @StinkingBishop Okay, so the resulting set is still open and dense I think: since you are considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus a "grid". Right?

Comment: @leslietownes Yes, I can convince myself about your hint

Comment: Thus, if I am not wrong, I understand that if $N$ is an arbitrary large integer I have no guarantees of finding a couple in $U$ where at least one co-ordinate has denominator $N$. Then, I slightly change the question: is there an integer $N$ (not prescribed) large enough which works? More precisely, can I always find a couple in $U$ where at least one co-ordinate in lowest terms has even denominator? I have the impression that this time the answer is yes

Comment: If by a "rational couple" you mean (q_1, q_2) where q_1 and q_2 are rational numbers, then you need to say "an ordered pair of rational numbers". And if by "at least one between q_1 and q_2" you mean *a rational number* between q_1 and q_2, then that is what you need to say. You also never say what you mean by "prescribed". Also, are you assuming q_1 ≠ q_2 ? If so, then you need to say so.

Comment: @DanAsimov Thank you for your corrections. I’m not assuming $q_1 \neq q_2$.

Comment: You may be interested in the dyadic rationals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you very much!